# What should I use? Hex codes, RGB codes, or color names in code?

Tags: html, css, colors

I just wanted to know, would there be a difference, or would it be better, if I use hex codes in HTML like `#000000`, RGB codes like `rgb(0,0,0)`, or color names like `black`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is truly up to your own preferences for most, but I usually avoid color names because you are depending on something else to translate the color. I avoid RGBA for now since it's gaining support but still not supported broadly enough. RGB though is a bit easier to manipulate in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. You can use all.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use the hexa code like `#000000` because name like black, white are label assigned by the browser for that kind of code so, maybe, some browser will not recognize them. hexa and RGB are the same (you can use both together without problems). The only advantage of using `RGB` is that you can declare the alpha direcly in the rule like `RGBA (RED, GREEN, BLUE, ALPHA LEVEL)` instEad of declare another css rule